# Finding Bodek Romaine Lettuce for Seder

Tags: kashrut-kosher, marror-bitter-herbs

I live in Riverdale, NY 10463, just north of Manhattan, south of Westchester. Where is the nearest store in New York City that sells Bodek Romaine Lettuce?

Thank you. Chag Sameach.